# Problem with theme activatation

Tags: customization

I have download the [Citizen Kane](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/citizen-kane) from WordPress theme repository.

When I am trying to activate it gives somthing like in the location `Dashboard->Appearence->Themes`

Broken Themes

The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a  stylesheet and a template.

Name    Description
Citizen Kane    The parent theme is missing. Please install the "bp-default" 
parent theme.`

Please help If any body have idea .I shall be very thanful to you all
I am waiting for ur reply

Answer (score 3):

This theme seems to be made for [Buddy Press](http://buddypress.org/) and declares that it is child of [bp-default](http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/the-bp-default-theme/) theme, which is not standalone - supplied with Buddy Press plugin.

I am not quite sure why it is in repository at all, as far as I know child themes are still not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried same error displayed for me,
The theme is either corrupted or some files are missing from it,
Better you try some different themes rather then this

Comment: No I can't bcoz my boss want only that theme.and he is saying fix the theme.

Comment: Hey its gives error parent theme missing may be there is any other thing which  need to download.

Comment: I think you need to ask this thing to the developer of the theme, or ask that person into the wordpress forums
try these links
http://go-themes.com/
http://twitter.com/modemlooper

Comment: @shalu - Your boss needs to realise the theme he/she wants isn't designed for use inside a regular WP install, it's specifically designed for use with BuddyPress.. do you have it installed or intend to?